# How to indicate that order was fully paid(invoiced) or refunded?

Tags: orders, invoice, creditmemo

I know one way:

```
base_grand_total = base_total_invoiced
base_grand_total = base_total_refunded
```

but I have that stupid rounding issues and this way is not convenient. Maybe you know something else? Compare qtys?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if an order is fully invoiced by calling: `$order->canInvoice()`. This may return false if the order is on hold or canceled. If that does not fit your needs you can check like this:

```
    $isInvoiced = true;
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()>0 && !$item->getLockedDoInvoice()) {
            $isInvoiced = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //do something with $isInvoiced
```

For credit memo you can check `$order->canCreditmemo()` but again you can get false positives. If that doesn't work for you try :

```
$isFullCretitmemo = false;
if (abs($order->getStore()->roundPrice($order->getTotalPaid()) - $order->getTotalRefunded()) < .0001) {
    $isFullCretitmemo = true;
}
//do someting with $isFullCretitmemo
```

Comment: hi @marius you have checked in order level but how to know whether the invoice is totally refunded or not. I mean if order contains multiple invoice's and if we try to refund then which invoice we have to pick and process refunds - Programmatically

Comment: please help me out